# Incorrect results for Prolog project/puzzle

Tags: prolog, maze

I am working in a hard Prolog project/puzzle but I cant find the solution. 
I would thank any help.

The practice is to model and solve logic programming through a maze. 
It consists of rooms, doors and keys. When two rooms are connected they are connected through a door which is closed by one or more locks, which will require to be opened to move from one room to the other. Keys and locks are indistinct , IE any key opens any lock. After opening a door it is always open, but the key's stuck in the lock and can not be recovered (lost forever), so that for opening each door they will take many keys and locks. In each room there can be unused keys, which can be collected for further opening new doors. Initially we have no keys.

The solution program must define a predicate camino / 3 (camino is road in Spanish) such that (`A`, `F`, `X`) is true if `X` is a road leading to the room `F` based on the stay, so that you can go opening the door with the keys corresponding available at all times. The road shall be calculated as a list of the names of the rooms in the order in which they cross (and thus starting at `A` and ending at `F`).

The program will define a predicate `e / 2` of the form `e (E , L )` for each room `E`, where `L` is the number of keys contained in that room. You also define a predicate `p / 3` of the form `p (E1, E2 , C)` for each door, where `C` is the number of locks having the door that connects `E1` and `E2` rooms. The program should maintain the state of the rooms (if they have keys or not) and doors (if already open or still 
locked) at all times.

An example would be ([Source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sblcsd18irfx061/example%20.jpg?dl=0)):

[image]

```
%rooms+ number of keys 
e(a,1). 
e(b,2). 
e(c,1). 
e(d,0). 
e(e,0). 
e(f,0). 

%Doors 
p(a,b,1). 
p(a,c,1). 
p(b,d,1). 
p(c,e,1). 
p(d,f,1). 
p(e,f,2).
```

Results should be:

```
?‐ camino(a,f,X). 
X = [a,b,a,c,d,f] ? 
yes 
?‐ camino(a,f,X). 
X = [a,c,d,f] ? 
yes
```

This is my current code. It finds its way to the destiny but it's not correct. Also I still haven't applied the cuts so that it only gives me one answer:

```
%CODE

% these are the rooms and the number of keys they contain
e(a,1).
e(b,2).
e(c,1).
e(d,0).
e(e,0). 
e(f,0).

%these are the doors and the number of keys needed to open them
p(a,b,1).
p(a,c,1).    
p(b,d,1).    
p(c,e,1).    
p(d,f,1).    
p(e,f,2).          

concatenate([],L,L).        
concatenate([X|M],L,[X|Y]) :-        
   concatenate(M,L,Y).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
camino(A,F,X):-    
   A==F,                     %check if we start at the destiny    
   concatenate([],[F],X).    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
camino(A,F,X):-    
   A\==F,                     %check if we dont start at the destiny    
   concatenate([],[A],R),    
   findRoad(A,F,0,R,X).    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%TRUE if x is a road (list) that leads to room F starting from A
%
findRoad(A,F,K,R,X):-     %k is key ---  initial keys    
    addkey(A,K,L),        %L new key--- number of keys after we add the keys of the room    
    pickkey(A),           %we put the number of keys of the room to 0    
    passDoor(A,L,P,_),    %P is position-- position of the new room    
    opendoor(A,P),        %we put the number of keys needed to pass the door to 0    
    P == F,               %we check if we have finished    
    concatenate(R,[P],X). %we concatenate the destiny and end   
findRoad(A,F,K,R,X):-     %k is key ---  initial keys   
    addkey(A,K,L),        %L new key--- number of keys after we add the keys of the room    
    pickkey(A),           %we put the number of keys of the room to 0    
    passDoor(A,L,P,L2),   %P is position-- position of the new room   

    opendoor(A,P),        %we put the number of keys needed to pass the door to 0    
    P \== F,              %we check we haven't finished   
    concatenate(R,[P],R2),%we concatenate the path we have for the moment   
    findRoad(P,F,L2,R2,X).

addkey(A,K,L):-    
    e(A,N),    
    L is K+N.    

passDoor(A,L,P,L2):-    
    p(A,P,W),    
    L2 is L-W,    
    L2 >= 0.   
passDoor(A,L,P,L2):-   
    p(P,A,W),   
    L2 is L-W,    
    L2 >= 0.    

pickkey(A):-    
    e(A,_) = e(A,0).    

opendoor(A,P):-    
    p(A,P,_) = p(A,P,0).       
opendoor(A,P):-    
    p(P,A,_) = p(P,A,0).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method, that does not provides the optimal path (in the sense of minimal number of steps between rooms), but fulfills the request is as following. Main rule is:

```
path( Orig, Dest, Res ) :-
   e( Orig, Keys ),
   nextDoor( Dest, [(Orig,Orig)], Keys, [_|OpenDoors] ), !,
   joinDoors( Orig, OpenDoors, [Orig], Res ), !.
```

that means, after init the number of keys with the keys of the initial room, algorithm will decide in which order the doors must be opened (nextDoor), and second will find the path between one door to next door in previous list.

The rationalle is: at a given moment, we have a set of open doors, and a set of rooms connected by these open doors. Movement across the area of open doors and visited rooms is free, doors are already open and visited rooms has not yet keys. Thus, we are only interested in decide which is the next door we must open. The rules to decide this order of doors to open is:

```
nextDoor( Dest, OpenDoors, _, Res ) :-
  visitedRoom( Dest, OpenDoors ), 
  !,
  reverse( OpenDoors, Res ). 

nextDoor( Dest, OpenDoors, Keys, Res ) :-
  /* choice a visited room */
  visitedRoom( Room, OpenDoors ), 

  /* next door not yet open */
  door( Room, NextRoom, DoorCost ),
  \+ member( (Room,NextRoom), OpenDoors ),
  \+ member( (NextRoom,Room), OpenDoors ),

  /* we can open door ? */
  DoorCost =< Keys,

  /* do not open doors to rooms already visited */
  \+ visitedRoom( NextRoom, OpenDoors ),

  /* ok, cross door and next one */
  e( NextRoom, RoomAward ),
  Keys2 is Keys-DoorCost+RoomAward,
  nextDoor( Dest, [(Room,NextRoom)|OpenDoors], Keys2, Res ).
```

where two utilities are used, one to provide bidirectional paths:

```
door(From,To,Cost) :-
  ( p(From,To,Cost); p(To,From,Cost) ).
```

and another one to find the rooms in the area of already visited ones (rooms connected by open doors):

```
visitedRoom( Room, OpenDoors ) :-
  ( member( (_,Room), OpenDoors ); member( (Room,_), OpenDoors ) ).
```

The second step is go from one door to the next door following the previous order.

```
joinDoors( _, [], Path, Res ) :-
   reverse( Path, Res ).
joinDoors( CurrentRoom, [ (RoomBeforeDoor, RoomAfterRoom ) | Q ], Path, Res ) :-
   roomToRoom( CurrentRoom, RoomBeforeDoor, [], Path2 ),
   append( Path2, Path, Path3 ),
   joinDoors( RoomAfterRoom, Q, [RoomAfterRoom|Path3], Res ).
```

where roomToRoom is a clasical algorithm to find a path (TODO: optimize to find the shortest path):

```
roomToRoom( DestRoom, DestRoom, Path, Path ) :- !.
roomToRoom( CurrentRoom, DestRoom, Path, Res ) :-
  door( CurrentRoom, NextRoom, _ ),
  \+ member( NextRoom, Path ),
  roomToRoom( DestRoom, NextRoom, [NextRoom|Path], Res ).
```

If we try with the data provided in the example:

```
e(a,1).
e(b,2).
e(c,1).
e(d,0).
e(e,0).
e(f,0).

p(a,b,1).
p(a,c,1).
p(b,d,2). /* corrected */
p(c,d,1). /* add */
p(c,e,1).
p(d,f,1).
p(e,f,2).
```

the result is:

```
?- path(a,f,Path).
Path = [a, b, a, c, d, f].
```

Comment: This answer possibly fulfills with description of the problem, but is not optimal in the sense that no shortest path is found. It will be welcome one answer that reaches also this objective.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt to solve it, however it gets stuck on infinite loops

%rooms + number of keys
e(a,1).

e(b,2).

e(c,1).

e(d,0).

e(e,0).

e(f,0).

%Doors

p(a,b,1).

p(a,c,1).

p(b,d,2).

p(c,e,1).

p(d,f,1).

p(e,f,2).

%PRÁCTICA

concatenate([],L,L).

concatenate([X|M],L,[X|Y]) :-

```
    concatenate(M,L,Y).
```

path(A,F,X):-

A==F,

concatenate([],[F],X).

path(A,F,X):-

A\==F,

concatenate([],[A],R),

pathfinder(A,F,0,R,[],[],*,*,X).

%TRUE if x is a road (list) that leads to room F starting from A

pathfinder(A,F,K,R,ROOM,DOOR,ROOM2,DOOR3,X):-       %k is key ---  initial keys

```
    addkey(A,K,L,ROOM,ROOM2),     %L new key--- number of keys after we add the keys of the room 

    passDoor(A,L,P,_,DOOR,DOOR3),             %P is position-- position of the new room   

    P == F,                                 %we check if we have finished  

    concatenate([P],[R],X).               %we concatenate the destiny and end
```

pathfinder(A,F,K,R,ROOM,DOOR,ROOM2,DOOR3,X):-         %k is key ---  initial keys

```
    addkey(A,K,L,ROOM,ROOM2),      %L new key--- number of keys after we add the keys of the room 

    passDoor(A,L,P,L2,DOOR,DOOR3),%P=new room L2 = new Nº of keys

    P \== F,                               %we check we havent finished

    concatenate([R],[P],R2),            %we add the room we are to the path

    pathfinder(P,F,L2,R2,ROOM2,DOOR3,_,_,X).       %
```

addkey(A,K,L,ROOM,ROOM):-

```
member(A,ROOM),             %checks if we hace visited the room

    L is K.                            % If so [ROOM] and Nº of keys wont change
```

addkey(A,K,L,ROOM,ROOM2):-

```
not(member(A,ROOM)),    %checks we havnt visited the room

    e(A,N),                           %we save the number of keys of the room in N

    L is K+N,                        %L is (Nº of previous keys)+ keys of the room

    concatenate([ROOM],[A],ROOM2). %we add A to the list of visited rooms
```

passDoor(A,L,P,L2,DOOR,DOOR):-

```
    member(p(A,P,_),DOOR),            %checks if you have passed that door

    L2 is L.                           %If you have allready passed it, the Nº of keys dont change
```

passDoor(A,L,P,L2,DOOR,DOOR3):-

```
    not(member(p(A,P,_),DOOR)),        %checks that you havent passed that door

    p(A,P,W),                                     %checks the door exists

    L2 is L-W,                                   %we substract to our keys the Nº of keys needed

    L2 >= 0,                                        %checks the result is > 0

    concatenate([DOOR],[p(A,P,_)], DOOR2), %we add the door to the list of used doors

    concatenate([DOOR2],[p(P,A,_)], DOOR3). % we add both ways in case we need to go back
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure to get the shortest path, you can use BFS search :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

%rooms + number of keys
e(a,1).
e(b,2).
e(c,1).
e(d,0).
e(e,0).
e(f,0).

%Doors
p(a,b,1).
p(a,c,1).
p(b,d,2).
p(c,d,1).
p(c,e,1).
p(d,f,1).
p(e,f,2).

% Doors are closed at the beginning of the puzzle
% state(CurrentRoom, NumberKeys, StateRooms, StateDoors)
init(state(a, 0, LstRooms, LstDoors)) :-
    setof(e(X,Y), X^Y^e(X,Y), LstRooms),
    setof(p(X,Y,Z, closed), X^Y^Z^p(X,Y,Z), LstDoors).

% final state
final(state(f, _, _, _)).

% skeleton of BFS search
:- dynamic(states/1).
puzzle :-
    retractall(states(_)),
    % set the initial state
    init(State),
    assert(states([[State]])),
    repeat,
        nextstates,
    % if we get to the final state,
    % eneded/1 succeeds with a path
    ended(Path),
    maplist(writeln, Path).

% test if we have finished the puzzle
% succeeds with a Path to the solution
% This BFS gives a reverse path to the solution
ended(Path) :-
    final(State),
    states(LstStates),
    % may be there is no solution ?
    (   LstStates = []
    ->  Path = []
    ;   include(=([State|_]), LstStates, Paths),
        Paths = [RPath|_],
        reverse(RPath, Path)).

nextstates :-
    retract(states(LstStates)),
    foldl(\States^Y^Z^(nextstates_one(States, NewStates),
               append(Y, NewStates, Z)),
          LstStates, [], LstNewStates),
        assert(states(LstNewStates)).

% First we search the rooms near the current room
% Next we build the new paths
nextstates_one([Head | Tail], NewStates) :-
    nextrooms(Head, LState),
    foldl([Head, Tail] +\X^Y^Z^(member(X, Tail)
             ->  Z = Y
             ;   append([[X, Head | Tail]], Y, Z)),
          LState, [], NewStates),
    % we must put a cut here,
    % if **ended(Path)** fails, we must continue at **repeat**
    !.

% fetch all the rooms near the current room
nextrooms(state(R, K, SR, SD), States) :-
    % we fetch keys (even when there is no more keys left !)
    select(e(R, Key), SR, TSR),
    NK is K + Key,
    sort([e(R, 0) | TSR], NSR),
    % we test all the doors
    foldl([R,NK,NSR,SD]+\X^Y^Z^(X = p(R1, R2, Keys, Open),
                    % can we go to the next door ?
                   (   select(R, [R1,R2], [NR])
                   -> (    Open = opened
                       % the door is opened, we came in without changint anything
                       ->  Z = [state(NR, NK, NSR, SD) | Y]
                       % the door is closed, have we enough keys ?
                       ;   (   Keys =< NK
                        ->  NK1 is NK - Keys,
                            select(p(R1, R2, Keys, Open), SD, TSD),
                        sort([p(R1, R2, 0, opened) | TSD], NSD),
                        Z = [state(NR, NK1, NSR, NSD) | Y]
                        ;   Z = Y))
                   ;  Z = Y)),
          SD, [], States).
```